# how to enable web-cam to record video?

Tags: applications, webcam

How to enable web-cam to record video.?

I like the inbuilt camera app want capture video with it.

is there any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there isn't, but I use cheese for my webcam.

`sudo apt-get install cheese`

It has many more options than the builtin camera. Yea, I would love to stick with the builtin stuff, but it needs many more features before it can be considered a full webcam program.

Comment: This won't work on `Freya`? it make the system stuck

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya If you have an issue installing something like cheese, open a new issue. I'm no longer running elementary at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Some times the webcam could be disabled. Try

```
xinput --list
xinput enable id-of-your-webcam
```

Comment: no no it isn't. webcam is working but It only allows to take pictures only no video